# Uploading VMDK/Raw files to a local datastore in ESXi 5 Free

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have my VMDK/RAW files on a Linux server which is connected to a CIFS share, I want to get them copied up to the local datastore of my standalone host running ESXi 5 free.  I mounted the CIFS share on my Win Desktop and used vSphere client to copy them to the datastore but it is going too slow < 1MB/s.  What are my other options?  Physically removing disks is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any I'm afraid, that's as quick as it'll get unless you can copy the files to an NFS server that can act as a datastore. Others have tried SCP'ing files but it's treated as such a low priority job that it's slower than the VIClient method you're using.

You're doing all you can.

Comment: Doesn't FastSCP do some tricks to get higher priority? Threaded/multipart stuff..

Comment: That's a possibility, to add that in, no experience of it myself and I'm always worried about touching an otherwise 'vanilla' host from a support perspective.

Comment: Is it this slow because of some issue with the vsphere client?  It says it will take 4000 minutes for 60GB!

Comment: No, it's to discourage what you're doing - that said that is quite slow.